# Need help structuring data

Tags: influxdb

I've a set of data that I thought I was setting up in the right way but when trying to view graphs in Grafana it's not presenting the way I want it to.  Cutting to the chase, here's my data sample:

```html
conquest,base=The_Spire,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=1 1436550221
conquest,base=Norhaven,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=1 1436550221
conquest,base=Jotuns_Outpost,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=1 1436550221
conquest,base=Tyrolian_Outpost,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=8979 1436550221
conquest,base=Infested_Depot,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=1955 1436550221
conquest,base=Brood_Nest,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=1 1436550221
conquest,base=SkyCom_Complex,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=1 1436550221
conquest,base=Red_Maw_base,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=1 1436550221
conquest,base=Seismic_Beacon,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=1 1436550221
conquest,base=Phobos_Station,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=1 1436550221
conquest,base=Asphodal_Nexus,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=1 1436550221
conquest,base=Cleave_Rock,guild=Hodor,guild_id=119890002 value=1 1436550221
conquest,base=The_Spire,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=1 1436551659
conquest,base=Norhaven,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=4755 1436551659
conquest,base=Jotuns_Outpost,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=6330 1436551659
conquest,base=Tyrolian_Outpost,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=7270 1436551659
conquest,base=Infested_Depot,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=7705 1436551659
conquest,base=Brood_Nest,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=1 1436551659
conquest,base=SkyCom_Complex,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=1 1436551659
conquest,base=Red_Maw_base,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=1 1436551659
conquest,base=Seismic_Beacon,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=1 1436551659
conquest,base=Phobos_Station,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=1 1436551659
conquest,base=Asphodal_Nexus,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=1 1436551659
conquest,base=Cleave_Rock,guild=Seraphs,guild_id=83310002 value=1 1436551659
```

What I wanted to see was each guild's points (value) for each base...so if I selected "Infested_Depot" then I'd see two sets of graph lines one for the Guild Hodor, and the other for Seraphs where the point plots would be for the timestamp and that guilds value..what I'm getting instead is just a single data series.

I'm using Grafana v2.0.2 and influxdb 0.9.1

Comment: Not sure why there's a down vote, what I'm trying to do is listed here: https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/concepts/schema_and_data_layout.html with the data collected being different.  If you want to down vote, that's fine, but please explain why so I can learn.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfluxDB implicitly merges all series that match a query, unless the GROUP BY clause explicitly separates them. You want a query along the lines of `SELECT SUM(value) AS guild_points FROM conquest WHERE base='Infested_Depot' AND time > now() - 1w GROUP BY guild`. I'm not sure how to make that a grafana-ism, but you'll need to put `guild` in the GROUP BY to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks - the group by was the key.  I thought that the Grafana needed the group by time interval that it auto populates.